# Split Function in Angular for a certain combination

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string which is like this:

```
  'Hello\r\nand World 15.6\n3'.
```

or it can be

```
  'Hello\r\nand World 15.6\nNA'.
```

and I want result which should split it like this:

```
  'Hello\r\nand World 15.6'
  '3'.
```

The code which I have written:

```
  var lines = string.split('\n');
```

which is producing result like this:

```
 'Hello\r'
 'and World 15.6'
 '3'.
```

What changes should I make in split() function to get the desired result?

Comment: Is this only for the specific string mention in the question or are there other examples as well?

Comment: So you want to split on \n only if followed by a number?

Comment: @acincognito Not specifically followed by a number but my main requirement is it shouldn't split '\r\n'( \r followed by \n)

Comment: @NicholasK There can be other variants like instead of number 'NA' can be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `\r\n` with something else, then `split` by `\n` and put back the replaced `\r\n`:

```
'Hello\r\nand World 15.6\n3'.replaceAll('\r\n', '&newline').split('\n').map(item => item.replaceAll('&newline', '\\r\\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with:

```
'Hello\r\nand World 15.6\n3'.split(/\n(?=\d)/);
```

Splits on every `\n` that is followed by a number.

Comment: Can you make some changes so that your split function is applicable for this kind of string as well:  'Hello\r\nand World 15.6\nNA'.

Comment: I think what you want is `/[^\r]\n/`, but it's not clear exactly what rules you want to follow in your question